# Local Http server on windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I use this code to write Windows Service that work as local http request server.

```
public void StartMe()
    {
        System.Net.IPAddress localAddr = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener server = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(localAddr, 1234);
        server.Start();
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        String data = null;
        while (RunThread)
        {
            System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            data = null;
            System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

            System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\MyLog.txt", true);
            sw.WriteLine(data);
            sw.Close();

            client.Close();
        }
    }
```

And i have some issues with this code:
First of all in the `data` string i get stuff like this after i write this URL in my browser `http://127.0.0.1:1234/helloWorld`

```
GET /helloWorld HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:1234
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: windows-1255,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

And i want to know how can i get only the `helloWorld` from this example. 
And the second issue is that i want the server will give response to the browser and it only give me to close the connection.

Comment: You have nothing that resembles an HTTP server here. It is a listening socket that accepts connections and writes the request to a file, nothing more. If you want to implement an HTTP server yourself (and believe me, you don't), take a look at the various RFC's, starting with 2616. If you explain what your ultimate goal is, better solutions can be opted, like @CSharpie's answer that points to the HttpListener class. Better even you could perhaps just write an .aspx or MVC page, all depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked something similiar a few days ago. 
Better implement the HTTPListener-Class. Makes life way easier.

See this Example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Your HelloWorld is retrieved like this:

```
HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext(); // Waits for incomming request
HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
string url = request.RawUrl; // This would contain "/helloworld"
```

And if you want to wait for more than just one request either implement the Asynchronos way or do it like this:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    while(listener.IsListening)
    {
        handleRequest(listener.GetContext());
    }

});
...

void handleRequest(HttpListenerContext context) { // Do stuff here }
```

That codesample came out of my head. It will probably take some fumbling arround for it to work nicely but i hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thank for the replay, but how i start that HTTP Server run?

Comment: listener.Start();

while(listener.IsListening) { var ctx = listener.GetContext() } The Getcontext methods then returns a contextObject for every rewuest.